# mds uses disk even though Spotlight indexing is disabled for the disk

Tags: hard-drive, spotlight, eject

I have an external hard drive. I often eject it. I noticed that around 80% of the time I need to force eject the hard drive instead of manually ejecting it. I ran this command to see what was using my disk, preventing me from ejecting it:

```
sudo lsof -xf +d /Volumes/myHardDrive/
```

The only process that usually comes up is `mds`. Now, I've searched this up on multiple websites and it seems this process is solely related to indexing your disk so that you can use it with Spotlight.

The only issue is that I've disabled Spotlight for my hard drive (in **System Preferences > Spotlight > Privacy**. `mds` shouldn't be causing any problems, but it does.

Comment: Is your external hard drive, by any chance, used for time machine backup? Indexing for time machine backups cannot be disabled.

Comment: It is an external drive, but it’s not a Time Machine drive